# Swagger UI does not show the externalValue URL contents while using @ExampleObject under @Content

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, quarkus

I am developing a Quarkus REST-based application where I would like to display the API on SwaggerUI. Alon with that I would like to display the example schema file on my SwaggerUI.

For the Schema file, I would like to read the contents from External URL. So I am using the `external value` of the `@ExampleObject` annotation but for some reason, it does not load the file contents from the URL. It just display:

```
{
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```

Following is the Java Resources file with my `Swagger` annotations:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.ExampleObject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.Parameter;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;

@Path("/api")
public class Resources{
    @POST
    @Path("/generate")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequestBody(description = "InputTemplate",
            content = @Content(examples = {
                    @ExampleObject(name = "Schema Example", externalValue = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
            }))
    public Multi<String> generateTestData(final Map<String, Object> input){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Following is the screenshot from the SwaggerUI where its not displaying my JSON file contents:
[image]

1. Can someone please explain to me how to add the External JSON file to the example Request Body?
2. Also, is there a way to loop over the list of files present in the external URL path so it can display them one by one in the drop-down? Like if I have a list of files in
   a GitHub folder, I can give the Folder URL so it can loop over files in that folder and display the contents and name in the drop-down of the Swagger UI?

Comment: I appears to be a problem in swagger: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433

Comment: @pringi That's really strange it's been really long time and still no fix for this. Is there any alternative that I can work on to make this work? Because I am really in need of this. I would like to show the data from the external URL in the SwagegrUI. Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: I guess that you have to "hack" "org.webjars:swagger-ui" jar, and change index.html as it is indicated here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433#issuecomment-901628267.

Comment: @pringi I am trying to do the work-around but I am unable to understand where I need to modify the `index.html` in the above-mentioned reference. I am using the Java application and `Maven open-API` dependency where can I find the `index.html` file?

Comment: That file is in dependency  "org.webjars:swagger-ui" jar